# Upgrades without reboot - what kinds of problems happen in practice?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, upgrade

If you update, what kinds of problems can happen before you reboot?  This happens especially frequently if you use unattended-upgrade to apply security patches.

Shared objects get replaced and so it is possible for programs to get out of sync with each other.

How long can you go safely before rebooting?

**Clarification:**

What I meant by "can programs get out of sync with one another" is that one binary has the earlier version of the shared object and a newly launched instance has the newer version of the shared object. It seems to me that if those versions are incompatible that the two binaries may not interoperate properly.

And does this happen in practice very often?

**More clarification:**

What I'm getting at is more along the lines that installers typically start/stop services that depend on a shared library so that they will get the new version of an API.  If they get all the dependencies, then you are probably ok.  But do people see installers missing dependencies often?

If a service is written to support all previous API versions compatibly, then this will not be an issue.  But I suspect that often it is not done.

If there are kernel updates, especially if there are incompatible ABI changes, I don't see how you can get all the dependencies.  I was looking for experience with whether and how things "tip over" and whether people have observed this in practice, either for kernel updates or for library/package updates.

Yes, this probably should have been put into ServerFault...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ is better place for your question.

Comment: Oops.  Any way to move it over?

Answer (score 4):

There are two versions of an executable file at any moment in time; the one in memory and the one in disk.

When you update, the one on disk gets replaced; the one in memory is the old one. If it's a shared object, it stays there until every application that uses it quits; if it's the kernel, it stays there until you reboot.

Bluntly put, if it's a security vulnerability you're updating for, the vulnerability stays until you load the (hopefully) patched version. So if it's a kernel, you aren't safe until you reboot. If it's a shared object, a reboot guarantees safety.

Basically, I'd say it depends on the category of the vulnerability. If it's security, restart whatever is affected. Otherwise, well, unless the bug is adversely affecting you, I wouldn't worry. If it's the kernel, I always reboot.

Comment: For binaries and shared libraries, you can use `lsof /` to determine which processes have (now deleted from disk) old versions still loaded in memory, and from there, possibly restart only affected services.  As for the kernel, I use [Ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/) to update without reboots.

Comment: There could be more than two versions, because you might have several copies of the same executable running following more than one update. Likewise, "in memory" and "on disc" is extremely blurred in the face of demand-loading and virtual memory.

Comment: Yes, rebooting or restarting apps is required to get the security patch.  But if someone doesn't reboot, are there situations where that can cause things to start failing or working strangely?

Comment: I know that whenever I update Firefox, if I don't restart it, it begins to act strange if I continue to use it.

Comment: @MarkR virtual memory is the memory an application believes it has. Where the operating system puts the application (ram or swap/pagefile) doesn't matter; that copy still hasn't been updated. Again, demand-loading is also irrelevant. It is a case of has the OS loaded the image or not. But I agree, 2+ copies can and does happen and is very likely.

Comment: @supercheetah yes, I also noticed that. I expect it's due to the complexity of FF (xulrunner+firefox-bin+...) that causes this, especially if FF uses `dlopen()` etc.

Comment: @Ninefingers, no "in memory" or "on disc" really doesn't make any difference to the kernel, loading an executable is a special case of memory-mapped files. After a file is deleted (i.e. replaced by a new version) it can continue to be memory-mapped and demand-loaded, so "in memory" isn't really a good term for an executable that is running, because none of its pages actually need to be in core just now.

Comment: Ok, well I'm clearly not understanding this, so feel free to fix that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453781/what-happens-when-you-overwrite-a-memory-mapped-executable

Comment: @MarkR, when the executable file of a running application is deleted, it is really only the filename that is removed. The now anonymous executable file is still there on the disk and it is still used as swap (i.e. no need to swap out .text section, since it can be reread from the file). You can even restore the old binary by doing something like `cp /proc/self/exe old_exe`.

Comment: @Ninefingers, I appreciate your response and apologize that my original wording didn't make clear enough what I was looking for.