# Writing to executing process' image on Linux

Tags: linux, image, process

What if process B writes (with a usual write() syscall) some data into the image of process A while the latter is executing ? Won't it cause corruption of what process A is executing ?

I'm new to Linux. As far as I understand, Unix historically does not impose mandatory file locks (like Windows does). So writing is quite possible.

I've searched the Web with no result. When I ask this question my Linux-experienced co-workers, they all answer that process A has its image entirely in-memory.

Nevertheless, from what I've read, the kernel can easily swap some pages back to the image file from memory, say, when low memory conditions are stressed. So, while on disk, some pages can potentially be corrupted by another writer process; afterwards, they can be swapped back into RAM and get executed.

Comment: Check there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453781/what-happens-when-you-overwrite-a-memory-mapped-executable

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of a process writing into some `/proc/1234/mem` of another process of `pid_t` 1234 ?

Or are you thinking of a process writing into the ELF executable of another process?

Both scenarii are very uncommon and Linux specific (other Posix don't have these), so I don't know what can happen in that case. But at least the permission machinery should protect some.

See also the `ETXTBSY` error.

In practice (as shown by `strace -f /usr/bin/gcc hello.c -o hello`) the compiler and linker are removing the executable before `open`-ing it for writing the executable, so most compilation never write into an old executable file:

```
870   stat("hello", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=6096, ...}) = 0
870   unlink("hello")                   = 0
870   open("hello", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0777) = 17
870   fstat(17, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

So to write into an executable file, you have to try hard. Of course, when you do that, naughty crashes can happen.

Comment: ETXTBSY is likely the biggest clue here, in my experience, you'll get an error of ETXTBSY if you're trying to overwrite parts of a running executable. And note that overwriting the content of a file is very different from removing the file and creating a new one with the same file name on posix systems.

Comment: The question linked by Antoine has the detail discussions. I think that ETXTBSY don't happen much anymore (except for statically linked executables perhaps).

Comment: @nos: yes, you're perfectly right. Removing a file implies only changes in parent directory's listing, that is, in inode tree structure. The file itself will remain alive and quite usable, as long as anyone still uses it; it would not just be referenced by any inode in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

What have you read that suggests pages may be swapped back "to the image file"?

If the system is low on memory, pages will be swapped to the swap partition on disk, which is different from the executable file.  Writing to the executable file will have no effect until the next time you run the file.

If, somehow you were able to write to the exact page on the swap file (which would be difficult, because you would have to know exactly where and when the data was written to disk). If you did that you might be able to modify the object code.  Are you suggesting corrupting the executable, or some clever way to change a program while it's running?

Comment: I'm concerned with the undesirable possibility of object code corruption. I have doubts that kernel uses the swap partition for executable images; it would be too wasteful, as far as I can think about it. The kernel rather maps images in a fashion similar to ordinary mmap.

Comment: Clean pages are not swapped out at all - they're simply dropped, to be reloaded from the file that they're mapped from if they're needed again.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's not necessary to have a "low memory condition" for pages to be swapped out. Linux loads executable files "on demand" anyway, so a page only gets loaded when it is required.

But see my answer to the previous one [What happens when you overwrite a memory-mapped executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453781/what-happens-when-you-overwrite-a-memory-mapped-executable)